# mutableCopy of NSInteger

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, nsinteger

I'm trying to make a mutableCopy of an `NSInteger`?. However, since an `NSInteger` is a non-mutable object this doesn't work. If I don't make a mutableCopy of the row variable the `UIPickerView` jumps to the next row when selecting one.

Here my code:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (pickerView == _frequencyPicker) {
        [_detailTableViewController.currentAlarm.cycles replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:row]];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    } else {
        int rowNumber = (int)row;
        // -> mutableCopy
        rowNumber++;
        NSLog(@"%s:%d",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,rowNumber);
        [_detailTableViewController.currentAlarm.cycles replaceObjectAtIndex: withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:row]];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Comment: NSInteger is not an object at all, it"s a primitive data type like int. I didn't understand what you were trying to do

Comment: i think he wants to have rowNumber and row point to the same integer

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `NSInteger`, not `NSNumber`, you can rewrite your code without declaring and incrementing a primitive variable, like this:

```
[_detailTableViewController.currentAlarm.cycles
    replaceObjectAtIndex:0
    withObject:@(row+1)];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Since `NSInteger` is a `typedef` for a primitive type, mutability considerations do not apply here.

Comment: I get a warning: Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'NSNumber *' to parameter of type 'NSInteger' (aka int)

Comment: @JavedGeorge What are you sending to `replaceObjectAtIndex:` parameter instead of zero?

Comment: @JavedGeorge That's very strange: the only line of code in the snippet above that sends any parameters is the first one, and it sends `NSNumber` for the second parameter, which is supposed to be of type `id`, not `NSInteger`. The error must be coming from some other place.

Comment: I think It's because I'm calling [NSNumber numberWithInteger:...] and for the Integer we use a NSNumber literal. I've replaced the whole statement -> [NSNumber numberWithInteger:...] with @(row + 1), now the warning disappeard but when I select a row in the simulator, the problem that the UIPickerView is jumping to the next row is still here.

Comment: @JavedGeorge Ah, I see - it should be one or the other, i.e. `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:row+1]` or `@(row+1)`. I like the NSNumber literal syntax, but it's definitely a matter of preference.